# JS - Comparing length of words in string, ignoring non-letter chars

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

This is a Coderbyte JS challenge.  The goal is to write a function that takes in a string and returns the longest word in the string. If two words are the same size the first word is returned. The input will never be empty.  For example, Input = "fun&!! time" will result in: Output = "time"

This question has been asked [before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65049/finding-longest-word-in-a-string), although the original question involved using a variety of string methods and a regexp.  I am a JS (and programming noob) and find this approach non-intuitive, and am trying to assess whether my alternate method is a feasible approach to this problem:

```
function LongestWord(sen) { 
  var count = '';
  var max = 0;
//loops thru string & tallies letters in sequences
  for (i = 0; i < sen.length; i++) {   
    if ((sen.charAt(i) >= 'A' && sen.charAt(i) <= 'Z') || 
        (sen.charAt(i) >= 'a' && sen.charAt(i) <= 'z')) {
            count += sen.charAt(i);
//conditional tracks longest letter string to date
            if (count.length > max){
                max = count;             
                } 
    }
//resets count if it encounters a non letter value in string
    else {
        count = '';
         }
    }
  return max; 
}
```

This seems to work in that it recognizes whether or not the first char is a letter or not and logs it to my var count, but its not iterating through the array as I'd expected.

Is this a valid approach?  Or do I need to learn more about string methods and regexp before I come back to this?  Thanks!

Comment: I think you want count += sen.charAt(i) to be count++.  Also, initialize count=0.  Other then that, what do you mean by it isn't iterating through list as you expected?

Comment: Yeah, you probably should take time to learn regular expressions.  They are very powerful if archaic at times.  I find this site really helpful for playing with regular expressions: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs due to the comparison of integer `count.length` with string `max`

This can be solved by initializing max to empty string `max = ''`
and compare the `count.length` to `max.length`

here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2mnyzha/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking for something like this:

```js
function LongestWord(sen) {
  var curWord = '';
  var longestWord = '';
  // Loops thru string & tallies letters in sequences
  for (i = 0; i < sen.length; i++) {
    var char = sen[i];
    if (/[A-z]/.test(char)) {
      curWord += char;
      if (curWord.length > longestWord.length) {
        longestWord = curWord;
      }
    }
    // Resets curWord if it encounters a non letter value in string
    else {
      curWord = '';
    }
  }
  return longestWord;
}
```

The forward slashes `/A-z/` says any letter uppercase or lowercase.  It's a really simple regular expression.

You need to keep track of that longest word as a string so you can return it.